# Downloading a module using url

Tags: lua, download, coronasdk

```
network.download(  url, "GET", function(e)
if (e.isError == false) then
    print("Download Successful")

    -- get the path of the downloaded file
    local path = system.pathForFile( "MyModule.lua" , system.TemporaryDirectory )

    -- Replace "/" with "." because that's how "require" works
    local newPath = string.gsub( path, "/", "." )

    -- Load the module
    local m = require ( newPath )   <<-- Error!

end
end, "MyModule.lua", system.TemporaryDirectory )
```

As you can see I'm trying to download a module from a url. The file indeed gets downloaded but when trying to load it using the `require` function I get this error:

```
File: module '<<path of the file>>.tmp.MyModule.lua' not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on this topic - https://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/27060-requiring-lua-file-from-documents-directory/

Seems like you cannot `require` / `loadstring` on real device.